# How to move script from view to application.js in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Doing some research this is the code that worked for me but it is in the view and I would like to move to the application.js so I can use in different forms.

The other thing is that I have two scripts doing the same thing. One is for when I click on the checkbox and the other is to check if it is already checked when loading the page. Can I merge them so I don't have to repeat the code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideAddress()
    {
        if($('#same').is(":checked"))
            $("#mailing-address").hide();
        else
            $("#mailing-address").show();
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function hideAddress() {
        {
            if ($('#same').is(":checked"))
                $("#mailing-address").hide();
            else
                $("#mailing-address").show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Edit

I tried moving to the application.js without the script tags, but now the .ready function doesn't work unless I reload the page.

```
$( document ).ready(hideAddress);


    function hideAddress()
    {
        if($('#same').is(":checked"))
            $("#mailing-address").hide();
        else
            $("#mailing-address").show();
    }
```

Comment: Can you use `$( document ).ready(hideAddress);` ?

Comment: I don't know about rails but.... if `application.js` is a JavaScript file (as I suppose it is) you can safely move that code there. Can you post a sample code on your `application.js`?

Comment: @lealceldeiro I tried to move to the file without the script tag but it doesn't really work on ready. If I reload the page it works. Would you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Yes, enclose it inside an [IIEF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) like this: `(function() { /*your code here! */} )();`

Comment: Also, the comment of @Titus, makes total sense. It should work.

Comment: i guess there was something to do with turbolinks on rails

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like turbolinks makes document ready not work properly, so instead of `(document).ready` I had to do `$(document).on('turbolinks:load'`.

So i ended up setting this code on my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .


    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', hideAddress );

    function hideAddress()
    {
        if($('#same').is(":checked"))
            $("#mailing-address").hide();
        else
            $("#mailing-address").show();
    }
```